# Hard code email address in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

The following is a simple code that will send an email using whatever email program is open. My problem is that I would like to add three emails to the list but outlook 2013 only recognizes it if I have one address.
What is the correct format for outlook?
`Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show _
 arg1:="attributes@hotmail.ca", _
 arg2:="East attributes" & Now()`

I have tried

`Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show _
 arg1:="attributes@hotmail.ca" & ";" & "runaway@gmail.com", _
 arg2:="East attributes" & Now()`

Comment: Why are you not using the Outlook Object Model?

Comment: This code was being used with groupwise email system but now we have changed to outlook. I know I misspelt Hotmail but that is not the answer. I thought I could just alter the original with the formatting of outlook.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.  Why are you not using Outlook objects?

Comment: I am not familiar with the outlook object model but I will look it up thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic example of how to automate Outlook from Excel. Please note I am using LateBinding.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim MyFileList(1) As String
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Change/Add the file names here
    MyFileList(0) = "C:\Sample1.xlsx"
    MyFileList(1) = "C:\Sample2.xlsx"

    '~~> Create a new instance of outlook
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    '~~> Create a new Email
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    '~~> Set the To/CC/BCC etc here
    With OutMail
        .To = "MyEmail1@123.com" & ";" & "MyEmail2@123.com" & ";" & "MyEmail3@123.com"
        .CC = "MyEmail4@123.com"
        .Bcc = "MyEmail5@123.com"
        .Subject = "Example for attaching 2 files"
        .Body = "Hi Russel :)"

        '~~> Attaching file
        For i = LBound(MyFileList) To UBound(MyFileList)
            .Attachments.Add MyFileList(i)
        Next i

        '~~> Display the email. To send the email, Change the below to .Send
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot**:

[image]

Comment: It works for the sending of the email but it is not including the attachments.

Comment: was the line under   For I = LBound(myfilelist) etc

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I had commented the line.

Comment: supposed to be a comment?

Comment: Remove the `'` before `.Attachments.Add MyFileList(i)`

Comment: I have updated the post. You may have to refresh the page to see it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can automate Outlook from Excel to get the job done. See [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/201096) for more information.

Use the [Recipients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866751.aspx) collection to specify the To, CC or Bcc recipients.

Comment: I tried the recipients collection code but it does not put the names in the To: address box